# Is there a way to handle locked file from command line and release it?

Tags: windows, command-line

Is there a way to detect locked files in specify folder and release them by command line? Something like this (pseudo code):

```
for file in folder
do 
   unlock file
done
```

Thanks

Comment: Is it alright if third party programs are used? [Sysinternals Handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655) can be used to list and close open handles. Open file/folder handles are what 'locks' files/folders. And yes, it is a command line program.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, using [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/#download2):

[image]

Simple use: `unlocker file /s`

Comment: Have you tried this? It doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @Robert It has been some while since I last used this utility but at the time I found it effective.  Are you running it with administrator permissions?

Comment: unlocker requires a full path including drive letter, i use it like that: `unlocker %cd%\foldername /s`